# CommonsRequestLoggingFilter does not log params in beforeRequest method

Tags: spring, logging, interceptor

I see Spring has a CommonsRequestLoggingFilter  using which we can do request logging.

But, when I try to use it I see 2 lines of log in the output.

one is for the beforeRequest method and the other is for the afterRequest method.

The params are not being displayed in beforeRequest but only in afterRequest method.

I do not want the log line which does not display the params, I  only want the line for afterRequest log which has the params.

Also, I want to understand why beforeRequest does not log the parameters.

Can someone help me on this.

thanks,

s

Answer (score 0):

It appears to not include the request body in the beforeRequest message because of how the inputStream is being handled within AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.

To have the filter not log the beforeRequest at all, you can extend CommonsRequestLoggingFilter, otherride beforeRequest, and have it not log out the request.

```
public class MyRequestLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {

@Override
protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
    // do nothing
}
}
```